# How to know if a password prompt is legit in macOS?

Tags: macos, icloud, security, password

See for example [Is this prompt for iCloud credentials legit?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/373787/is-this-prompt-for-icloud-credentials-legit), [ICloud Password prompt](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/230748/icloud-password-prompt), and other similar questions, where a dialog pops up in MacOS asking for the user's password.

As a user, I presume it would not be difficult for a malicious software to simulate this dialog and request the password.

So, when I see a dialog asking for my password, is there a way to determine whether the dialog is legitimate (i.e., from macOS / Apple) or not?

Comment: Not writing as an answer, since it isn't really - but the easiest way is causality. Do you understand why and expect the alert. If you see an alert you don't expect, dismiss it and then go through the proper process (ie if you see a random iCloud prompt dismiss it then open iCloud settings and see if there's still a prompt)